# JavaFX LineChart - save transparent image

Tags: java, javafx, background-color, linechart

I am trying to save a javaFX LineChart as a PNG and I would like the background to be transparent. If I do:

```
SnapshotParameters spa = new SnapshotParameters();
spa.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
chart.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width,height);
spa.setTransform(Transform.scale(x,y));
WritableImage img= chart.snapshot(spa, writableImage);
```

I end up with something like this:

[image: img 1]

As you can see here, the Axis ticks and label get transparent but the plotting area itself still has the background grey color. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Load up your chart in [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) and use that tool to introspect on the components of the chart to determine which ones are providing the non-transparent area.  Or extract modena.css from jfxrt.jar in your JRE directory and read that to find out what css style is setting the chart background color.  Or read up on [styling charts with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm#CIHGIAGE) (though be aware that some of the info in the chart styling tutorial is outdated - it does supply transparent background info though).

Comment: @jewelsea That worked thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already done it with the tip jewelsea you provided, you can add a stylesheet to your chart with the following content:

```
.chart > .chart-content > .chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```